# Why is QGIS rounding off manually added decimal attributes?

Tags: qgis

I am manually adding a decimal column in qgis and set the width and precision to one more than I actually need (Width: 5, Prec: 5)so the number comes out as 0.XXXXX, but when I save my eidts qgis is still rounding the decimal off at 3 places (0.XXX00).

Answer (score 1):

You have to set a `Width` value greater than the `Precision` value.

If you want 5 digits behind the period, the width has to be 7 to include the period and the 0 (or sign) before it. If the numbers are greater than 10, you have to expand the width as well.

Don't be shy with the width value, it was a delimiter in old FORTRAN times when data storage was expensive.

Comment: There's no reason to set width greater than necessary, though that may be precision+3 when negative values are present.  The derogatory reference to FORTRAN is misleading, at best.

Comment: I was not taking the period into account, that was my problem. Awesome, thanks.